# Chair felt pads that stay on

Tags: furniture

I've got some [Ikea Vilmar](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S19889748/) chairs that have a sort of swivel base and thin legs, and I'm trying to put some felt pads on the chair, but no matter what I try, I can't get them to stay on. They'll come off once someone moves the chair rather quickly since the legs tend to wobble.

Any suggestions? Would supergluing it on help at all?

Answer (score 3):

I recently gave up on the felt pads when I saw an odd alternative on Amazon:

[NancyProtectz Ribbed Furniture Sock](http://smile.amazon.com/Chocolate-Brown-Furniture-Protector-Protection/dp/B0040IJG5I?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o09_s00)

[image]

These may not be the least obtrusive furniture feet and might not lend to the modern look or feel of the Ikea chairs, but I've been using them on square, wooden furniture legs for a few months and they do fairly well sliding across 100-year old hardwood floors. None of them have fallen off yet, but they do occasionally need to be "hiked-up".

Comment: You probably can avoid sag with a couple drops of rubber cement or ShoeGoo inside the top of the sock.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use those little peel and stick felt pads, forget it. Those things will never last, no matter how you try to attach them.

If this was a wooden chair, I'd say use a nail on foot. Since it's a metal leg, you'll have to find something that attaches via bolt, or some other means.

I'm not familiar with these chairs, but some types of chairs have feet that are threaded into the bottom of the leg.  If this is the case, you could remove the existing feet. Then find a suitable foot with a matching thread, that could be threaded in instead.

Comment: I've used the peel and stick felt pads for years now. Never had a problem with them sticking.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you couldn't use the self-adhesive pads and augment them with small brads. I'd look for round-headed ones and make sure you drive them well into the felt with a nail set. This assumes that the plastic foot on the chairs is substantial enough to take a nail.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a Nail on foot would definitely be the best solution, you could even add superglue to make sure it never comes out again if you really want. I think that most of the felt solutions, or 'sock' styles as seen above make your Chair or piece of Furniture look pretty ridiculous so i'd avoid them.

Alternatively you could always look at Rubber ferrules or Anti-marking plastic ferrules, these slip over the Chair leg and work the same way in protecting the floor and the chair leg itself.